# Getting all papers other than the papers that a certain student has bought already in laravel MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I have a Database with Student, Paper and payment tables and i need to get all papers that the student has already bought previously. the sample of my migrations are below-
paper

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('fname');
        $table->string('lname');
        $table->string('district');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
```

-payments

```
Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('paper_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('paper_id')->references('id')->on('papers');
        $table->float('amount');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

the code i have tried gives me the wrong data,

```
     $papers = DB::table('papers')
    ->leftJoin('payments','payments.paper_id','=','papers.id')
    ->orderBy('papers.price','ASC')
    ->select('papers.*')
    ->where('papers.id','<>','payments.paper_id')
    ->get();
```

can anyone please help.

Comment: Post sql syntax for table schema and query not migrations,also if possible sample data

Comment: what kind of end results do you want?

Comment: Sorry about the question edit. i had asked the wrong question

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara i need to see the records of the papers that the student hasn't already bought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using where raw like this

```
DB::table('papers')->whereRaw('id Not in (Select paper_id FROM payments)')->get();
```

Or you can also add student id to get optimized results like this

```
DB::table('papers')->whereRaw('id NOT IN (Select paper_id FROM payments where stduent_id='.$student_id.')')->get();
```